# Deleting Numbers sheets by name with Applescript

Tags: numbers, applescript

I'm working on a large payroll spreadsheet and would like to create code that would delete specific unnecessary worksheets within the document. Is there applescript that would remove those worksheets? Better yet, is there a way to create a new document from a specific sheet?

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and your desired result?

Comment: “You do payroll in that thing? You’re braver than I thought!” (with apologies:)

Comment: In principle, you should be able to use the `duplicate` command to copy a worksheet object (or objects) from one document to another. In practice, the only way to know is to actually try it, bearing in mind that the exact incantation may vary from app to app (or even object to object) so some educated guesswork/blind trial-and-error may be involved. Beyond that, as mypetition says, please [show your workings](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).